# Access HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key on Windows Embedded Standard 7 without admin privileges

Tags: windows-registry, windows-embedded-7

I have an application that needs to read some Registry keys from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch. The application works with no problems when an administrator is logged in, but when a regular user is logged in the application crashes and it tells me I need to have administrator privileges.

How can I make this application work for a regular user?

The application works with no problem on regular Windows 7 and Windows 8 both with an Admin user or regular user.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't, why are you putting user application data in the sytem level registry location instead of the user location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Registry, grant Read permissions to the `Users` group on the keys that the application needs to access. You can use [Process Monitor](http://live.sysinternals.com/procmon.exe) to figure out which keys those are. This works great if all the application needs is *Read* access as you state.

Chances are that's *not* all the application requires, in which case Process Monitor can help you figure out what other things the program is trying to access.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you so much! Sorry I can't give you a vote up because I am new and still do not have enough points to give a vote up.